# google play services error login 10002

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

i am using unity c#
when install apk from computer to my mobile it work nice and i login to google play services without problems .
but when upload apk to play store and install it from play store i always get 10002 error.

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="\ 420707679966" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="\ 420707679966" />
```

Comment: What certificate are you using? While you're at it, check this [Upload an app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en) to check if you've followed all the necessary steps.